# Converting a simple html/css page to wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I just created a basic html page layout and im currently trying to get it work on wordpress, created the header.php, index.php, footer.php, called them with php, well i followed this guide: https://thethemefoundry.com/blog/html-wordpress/

Did all thats on there, after i uploaded the theme and actived it i get this:

[image: Wordpress site after applied the theme]

No divs, no images, just the text

I will include my code bellow of the original html/ css and the php files:

```css
/*
Theme Name: SSK theme
Theme URI: 
Description: Tema para o site da ssk
Version: 1.0
Author: DA
Author URI: www
*/

body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, li, dl, dt, dd, img, form, fieldset, input, blockquote {
 margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;
}

body {
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
    line-height: 24px;
 background: #eee url(images/body-bg.jpg) center top no-repeat;
 width:100%;
 height: 100%;
}

#container {
 width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height:1100px;
    margin-top: -75px;
}

#container p {
    margin-bottom: -50px;
    color: #0066FF;
    font-size: 25px;
}

#languages {
 background-color: red;
 height:22px;
 width: 200px;
 position: absolute;
   top:60px; right: 125px;
}

#destaques {
 margin-top: 75px;
 width:100%;
 background-color: grey;
}

#main_page_holder {
    border-top: 2px solid blue;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 110px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
}

#home_navigation_link {
 margin-left: 1.7%;
 margin-right: 1%;
 margin-top: 2%;
    width: 30%;
    height: 35%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
  }

#Projetos {
    margin-top: 110px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    background-color: orange; 
}

#projsquare {
    border-top: 2px solid blue;
    margin-top: -0px;
    height: 30%;
}

.squa {
    width: 125px;
    float:left;
    height:125px;
    background:magenta;
    margin:10px;
    margin-top: 90px;
}

#logo2 {
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

#logo2 img {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
}

.ima {
    background-image: url("img/logo.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
 width:35%;
 height:100%;
 background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    -moz-border-radius: 60%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 60%;
    border-radius: 60%;
    border-color:white;
}

.ima img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 60%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 60%;
    border-radius: 60%;
    border-color:white;
}

.tit {
    color: #0066FF;;
 float:left;
 width:65%;
 height:15%;
}

.tito {
    width:65%;
    height:15%;
    background-color: black;
}


#categories {
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 125px;
    right: 125px;
    font-size: 0;
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#1b75b1+0,529282+47,71ac4a+100 */
    background: rgb(27, 117, 177);
    /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;
    base64, 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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgb(27, 117, 177) 0%, rgb(82, 146, 130) 47%, rgb(113, 172, 74) 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgb(27, 117, 177)), color-stop(47%, rgb(82, 146, 130)), color-stop(100%, rgb(113, 172, 74)));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgb(27, 117, 177) 0%, rgb(82, 146, 130) 47%, rgb(113, 172, 74) 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgb(27, 117, 177) 0%, rgb(82, 146, 130) 47%, rgb(113, 172, 74) 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgb(27, 117, 177) 0%, rgb(82, 146, 130) 47%, rgb(113, 172, 74) 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(27, 117, 177) 0%, rgb(82, 146, 130) 47%, rgb(113, 172, 74) 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#1b75b1', endColorstr='#71ac4a', GradientType=1);
    /* IE6-8 */
}
#categories li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;  
    position: relative;
}
#categories li a {   
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 6px 22px;
    display: block;    
}
#categories li:before{
    content: '';
    width: 1px;
    height: 15px;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
}
#categories li:first-child:before{
    background: none;
}

#header {
    overflow: hidden;
 padding: 0 0 50px 0;
}

#mllcont {
 height:40vh;
    background-image: url("img/header.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#slidecont {
    background-image: url("img/back.jpg");
 height:100vh;
 background-color: red;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#slidecont img {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

#squares {
    width:100%;
    height:250px;
    position: relative;
}

#divs p {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -100px;
    color: #0066FF;
    font-size: 25px;
}

#divs div { 
    height: 300px; 
    width: 20%; 
    border: 0px solid red; 
    margin-left: 2.5%; 
    margin-right: 2.5%; 
    float: left; /*Here you can also use display: inline-block instead of float:left*/
    background: white;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.circle{
    border:1px solid red;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
    -moz-border-radius: 40px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    position: relative;
}

#header h1 {
 float: left;
}


#content, #footer, #header  {
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Particle</title>

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

</head>

<body>

<!--1 parte-->

 <div id="slidecont">
  <img src="img/banner.png"/>
  <div id="mllcont">

   <div id="logo">
   </div>

   <div id="languages">
   </div>
     <ul id="categories">
         <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Menu4</a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
 </div>

<!--1 parte-->

<!--2 parte-->

 <div id="container">
   <div id="squares">
       <div id="divs">
          <div> <div class="tito"> </div> </div>
          <div> <div class="tito"> </div> </div>
          <div> <div class="tito"> </div> </div>
          <div> <div class="tito"> </div> </div>
       <p> Destaques </p>
       </div>
   </div> 

    <div id="main_page_holder">
     <div id ="destaquetex">
      
     </div>
     <div id="home_navigation_link">
      <div class="ima">  </div>
      <div class="tit"> &nbsp; Nova liderança SKK </div>
     </div>
     <div id="home_navigation_link">
      <div class="ima"> <img src="img/2.jpg"> </div>
      <div class="tit"> &nbsp; Descontaminação </div>
     </div>
     <div id="home_navigation_link">
      <div class="ima"> <img src="img/3.jpg"> </div>
      <div class="tit"> &nbsp; ISOAIR </div>
     </div>
     <div id="home_navigation_link">
      <div class="ima"> <img src="img/4.jpg"> </div>
      <div class="tit"> &nbsp; SmartPower </div>
     </div>
     <div id="home_navigation_link">
      <div class="ima"> <img src="img/4.jpg"> </div>
      <div class="tit"> &nbsp; Móveis de congelação </div>
     </div>
     <div id="home_navigation_link">
      <div class="ima"> <img src="img/6.jpg"> </div>
      <div class="tit"> &nbsp; Universal R </div>
     </div>
    </div>

    <p> Projetos</p>
    <div id="projsquare">
     <div class="squa"> </div>
     <div class="squa"> </div>
     <div class="squa"> </div>
     <div class="squa"> </div>
     <div id="logo2"> <img src="img/logo.png"> </div>
    </div>


 </div> 

<!--2 parte-->

<!--3 parte-->

  <div id="footer">
  


  </div>

<!--3 parte-->


</body>
</html>
```

The files from the theme:

**INDEX.PHP**

```
  <?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="container">
            <div id="squares">
                <div id="divs">
                      <div> <div class="tito"> </div> </div>
                      <div> <div class="tito"> </div> </div>
                      <div> <div class="tito"> </div> </div>
                      <div> <div class="tito"> </div> </div>
                      <p> Destaques </p>
                </div>
            </div>  

                <div id="main_page_holder">

                    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                            <div class="post-header">
                                <div class="date"><?php the_time( 'M j y' ); ?></div>
                                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                                <div class="author"><?php the_author(); ?></div>
                                </div><!--end post header-->

        <div class="entry clear">
            <?php if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <?php edit_post_link(); ?>
            <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
        </div><!--end entry-->

        <div class="post-footer">
        <div class="comments"><?php comments_popup_link( 'Leave a Comment', '1 Comment', '% Comments' ); ?></div>
        </div><!--end post footer-->
        </div><!--end post-->

        <?php endwhile; /* rewind or continue if all posts have been fetched */ ?>
        <div class="navigation index">
            <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older Entries' ); ?></div>
            <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' ); ?></div>
         </div><!--end navigation-->

<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>

                    <div id ="destaquetex">

                    </div>
                    <div id="home_navigation_link">
                        <div class="ima">  </div>
                        <div class="tit"> &nbsp; Nova liderança SKK </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="home_navigation_link">
                        <div class="ima"> <img src="img/2.jpg"> </div>
                        <div class="tit"> &nbsp; Descontaminação </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="home_navigation_link">
                        <div class="ima"> <img src="img/3.jpg"> </div>
                        <div class="tit"> &nbsp; ISOAIR </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="home_navigation_link">
                        <div class="ima"> <img src="img/4.jpg"> </div>
                        <div class="tit"> &nbsp; SmartPower </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="home_navigation_link">
                        <div class="ima"> <img src="img/4.jpg"> </div>
                        <div class="tit"> &nbsp; Móveis de congelação </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="home_navigation_link">
                        <div class="ima"> <img src="img/6.jpg"> </div>
                        <div class="tit"> &nbsp; Universal R </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <p> Projetos</p>
                <div id="projsquare">
                    <div class="squa"> </div>
                    <div class="squa"> </div>
                    <div class="squa"> </div>
                    <div class="squa"> </div>
                    <div id="logo2"> <img src="img/logo.png"> </div>
                </div>


    </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**Header.php**

```
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<?php wp_head(); ?>

<div id="slidecont">
    <img src="img/banner.png"/>
    <div id="mllcont">

        <div id="logo">
        </div>

        <div id="languages">
        </div>
                <ul id="categories">
                    <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Menu4</a></li>
                </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**footer.php**

```
  <div id="footer">



</div>
```

Comment: Your code generates invalid HTML (missing head, body, ...) and the link to the stylesheet is missing. I suggest you to read more on HTML in general and then on WP themes.

Comment: Where should the stylesheet link be ? in what file

Comment: @DuarteAndrade you need to set the file path of your images and stylesheets relative to your theme folder. Check my answer below to read how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use links, such as

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

Wordpress needs to know the *path to your css file*. Your normal built is somehow like this:

```
index.php
/wp-content/
/wp-content/themes/
/wp-content/themes/theme_name/
/wp-content/themes/theme_name/index.php
/wp-content/themes/theme_name/style.css
/wp-content/themes/theme_name/images/
/wp-content/themes/theme_name/images/image.jpg
```

So the `file path` needs to be relative to your `theme folder`. You can use a php snippet, to get the url of your theme:

```
<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>
```

If you want to include that, you can change your urls. For example

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<img src="images/image.jpg">
```

turns into:

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/image.jpg">
```

Do this to all file paths using `src` or `href` inside your `index.php`, `header.php`, `footer.php`, and other `php files`.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to link eg css/js files to your site is via functions-file.

Create file functions.php to your folder /wp-content/themes/theme_name/ with this content:

```
function scripts_here() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'stylename', get_template_directory_uri() . '/path_to_your_css.css' );


}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scripts_here' );
```

If you need to more css files, just use wp_enqueue_style-function..Take a look: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style